# How to fade out and fade in paragraph in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want paragraph to fade out,I tried many time I've failed in jQuery.

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<p class="alert-success">Succefull</p>
@endsection

@section('script')

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.alert-succes').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
</script>
@stop

//document.write() work correctly I don't where is problem.
```

Comment: Closing curly brace is missing after fadeOut

Comment: And I think it's not related to Laravel.

Comment: I add curly brace at end but problem is not solve.

Comment: @ObossChacha What is the response you are getting on the console?

Comment: @Coder Thank,the problem was in master page jquery cdn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have a typo in your javascript, its `alert-success` NOT `alert-succes`. It should be

```
$('.alert-success').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
```

Comment: I changed the class and refresh again but nothing change any help please!!!

Comment: Can I see your `layouts/master.blade.php`?

Comment: @ aceraven777 you saved my day,The problem was in master page cdn.Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer as best answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you have made two mistakes

1. You did not close your brackets properly
2. You did not call your class properly. There is a spelling mistake!

Refer the working snippet below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.alert-success').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast')
       });
</script>

<p class="alert-success">Succefull</p>
```